# Find_in_set taking too much time in mysql query

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

My Query performance is very very bad. It is taking around.

```
SELECT t1.from_state_id fromStateId,GROUP_CONCAT(t3.state_name) fromState 
FROM tbl_vendor_workstations as t1  
Left JOIN tbl_states as t3 ON find_in_set(t3.id,t1.from_state_id) 
where t1.vendor_id=1717 and enterprise_user_id=703 
group by t1.id
```

issue is in that function **find_in_set(t3.id,t1.from_state_id)**

Column t1.from_state_id: 1,2,3,4,5,...,45147 it contains **50,000 separated by comma**

Comment: If you have a comma separated list as string in a column, with 50,000 items, your schema is broken. Normalise your database.

Comment: When you take the Denormalization to increase performance to heart.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Please suggest me for normalise it. kindly share any code or reference. it would be really thankful for me.

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You probably want some kind of coupling table between `tbl_vendor_workstation` and `t3`. Without full domain description and your schema it's hard to say though.